# Unable to set adapter on recyclerview, error - Cannot resolve 'setAdapter'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, android-recyclerview

Ive been trying to set the adapter on my main page, but was unable to get it working through .setAdapter, it always comes as `Cannot resolve symbol 'setAdapter'`

i have tried to change the imports from:

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

to:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

but none seem to work

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rv = findViewById(R.id.rvtop);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mRv;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_feiticos);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    mRv = new GridLayoutManager(this.getBaseContext(),1);

    Context context;
    DatabaseHandler banco = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = banco.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from feiticos", new String[]{});
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
        spell_nome.add(cursor.getString(1));
        spell_nivel.add(cursor.getString(2));
        spell_cast_time.add(cursor.getString(3));
        spell_range.add(cursor.getString(4));
        spell_duration.add(cursor.getString(5));
        spell_classe.add(cursor.getString(6));
    }
    while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    FeiticosRecycler adapter = new FeiticosRecycler(this,spell_nome,spell_nivel,spell_cast_time,spell_range,spell_duration,spell_classe);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

i expected to get setAdapter to get working since i already did it once in another project i was hoping to get it working again, also in the other project i was using `android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0` and not `androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0`

Comment: Can you show me the xml of R.id.rvtop and the type of rv?

Comment: What is rv in your Activity?

Comment: rv is the recycler view in my activity, in the java class is the variable i use for the recycler view rv = findViewById(R.id.rvtop)

Comment: show where you declare `rv`

Comment: i declare rv before the onCreate as RecyclerView rv

Comment: Which class does `FeiticosRecycler` extend?

Comment: xml for rvtop 

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvtop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

Comment: In any case move `rv = findViewById(R.id.rvtop);` after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_feiticos);`

Comment: i did it and still android studio doesn't bring up setAdapter for the rv

Comment: No idea. Check if all classes use androidx package.

Comment: ye i have no idea as well, a friend knows more than me in java and is trying to help and either of us was able to fix it. Ill take a look

Comment: they all do use androidx package, its weird cause android studio gives me Recycler (androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView) when i press ctrl + spacebar.

Answer (score 0):

You are finding view of recyclerview using findViewById before the content view is setting. Thats why it is not finding the required view of recyclerview.

Change these lines to this order

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_feiticos) ;
rv = findViewById(R.id.rvtop);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mRv;
```